# Instantiating a View Controller programmatically with Storyboard from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I'm busy building an app - that when launched for the first time it asks the user to do two things:

1. Select a Country
2. Accept T&Cs

From there it goes to the home view controller.

The problem I am currently facing is pushing the first view controller onto the screen from my app delegate. I'm using storyboards / Xcode 5/ iOS7

Here is the code I came up with:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
BBCounterySettingsViewController *controller = (BBCounterySettingsViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"CountrySettings"];
[navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

The problem is the app crashes when it hits the last line of code with the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x8e9a400'

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're expecting the `self.window.rootViewController` to be a `UINavigationController` but it's a `UIViewController`. This means that the outermost view controller in your storyboard is of the wrong type.

A better way to obtain the `UINavigationController` (Which should work in this case) is to use the property `self.navigationController` on any `UIViewController`.

From what I understand you want to present a view the first time the user runs to have the user pick some stuff. What you should then do is present a modal view controller, like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
//isFirstRun is some boolean you use to determine if it's the first run
if(isFirstRun){
    BBCounterySettingsViewController *controller = (BBCounterySettingsViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"CountrySettings"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I think I am taking this approach the wrong way. This view controller doesn't need to navigate anywhere else. Just needs to be dismissed. The rest of the app is a tab bar based app. In the app delegate self.navigationController doesn't exist?

Answer (score 7):

There are two things you need to do:

1. In Storyboard you have mentioned the controller name (eg LoginView) and enable use storyboard ID
2. Then you have user the below line

   ```
   loginView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
   [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:loginView animated:NO];
   ```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you're still having the issue.

Comment: If embed your viewController in some UINavigationController, your can also use `instantiateInitialViewController()` method thom `UIStoryBoard`. This automatically loads the viewController marked with an arrow on your storyboard. If this viewController is a container, its children will load too.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"buyListSegue" sender:sender];
```

Comment: Not helpful. Segues cannot happen from the AppDelegate or viewControllers no part of a UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

I think the controller identifier `"CountrySettings"` is set to the wrong controller. You're not getting a `NavigationController` where you can call `pushViewController`...

Comment: Solved the problem, thanks. Marked answer was the issue.