# iOS UIImageView not displaying the image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

I have two view controllers in my application,One controller captures a photo using the AVCapturSession

I am writing this,

```
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
     if (exifAttachments)
     {
         // Do something with the attachments.
         NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
     }
     else
         NSLog(@"no attachments");

     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *displayimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

     SecondViewController *sec = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
     sec.showTakenPic.image = displayimage;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
 }];
```

The SecondViewController contains a UIImageView whose image I am setting to display image but the image is not getting set.

My SecondViewController is made from storyboard,

The SecondViewController.h looks like this,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property(atomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *showTakenPic;

@end
```

The SecondViewController.m looks like this,

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The image is not visible in the UIImageView why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You have to first load the controller from storyboard

[Instantiating a View Controller programmatically with Storyboard from AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540125/instantiating-a-view-controller-programmatically-with-storyboard-from-appdelegat)

set identifier as per this image [image]

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
 SecondViewController *controller = (SecondViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SecondViewController"];
```

Then

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    sec.showTakenPic.image = displayimage;
});
```

It is main thread issue

**Choice-2**

```
if (imageData)
{
 UIImage *displayimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

 SecondViewController *sec = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
 sec.showTakenPic.image = displayimage;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Sir, showTakenPic is IBOutlet, he have to load from storyboard compulsary

Comment: I agree your point , think this scenario also, before `imageData` conversion the page will navigate also the image does not appear

Comment: My SecondViewController is not a navigationController so can I push it like this ?

Comment: @AvinashSharma You can push it but instantiation from storyboard is compulsary

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik agree sir but if there is no image, still loading from nib is compulsary

Comment: You mean I need to do this
SecondViewController *sec = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: @AvinashSharma -- ya

Comment: you are using XIB or storyboard?

Comment: @techloverr storyboard

Comment: UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
SecondViewController *controller = (SecondViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SecondViewController"];

Comment: Gives Error, On the line 
SecondViewController *controller = (SecondViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SecondViewController"];

Used type "SecondViewController" where arithematic or pointer type required

Comment: in debug or build time?

Comment: UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
this throws an exception

Comment: @AvinashSharma is your storyboard name Main_iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

First, of all check if image is not nil.
Second, try setting image after pushing view controller.

```
if (displayimage)
{
     SecondViewController *sec = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];
     sec.showTakenPic.image = displayimage;
     sec.showTakenPic.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"displayimage is nill");
}
```

Comment: The display image is not nil but even after setting the image UIImageView is showing nil

Comment: Yes still gives me a black screen

Answer (score 0):

How big is the image and which color is it? If the image is way bigger than the UIImageView and that the ContentMode property is not properly set, you might only see a small black part of your image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set image when SecondViewController is Loaded in memory.. take a ivar of type UIImage and when the controller in pushed into stack use ivar to set image on showTakenPic imageView.

```
UIStoryboard mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
 SecondViewController *controller = (SecondViewController *)  
[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
controller.imageToSet = imagePickedFromFirstController
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller];
```

you can add this code into viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear of SecondViewController

```
self.showTakenPic.image = self.imageToSet
```

or anything you are using for segue!

Answer (score 0):

You should set image indirectly into your Second view controller.

```
FirstViewController.m

SecondViewController *postImageViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

[postImageViewController setImage:image];

SecondViewController.h

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {

    UIImage * postImage;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (void)setImage:(UIImage*)image;

@end

SecondViewController.m

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if(postImage) {

        _imageView.image = postImage;

    }

}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage*)image {

    postImage = image;

}
```